# "either" in a response

Tags: also-too

If someone says "I'm not doing it". Which of the following responses are 
grammatically right.

- I'm not doing it either.
- I'm not doing it as well.
- I too am not doing it.
- I also am not doing it.

Comment: `I am not doing it too`, `I'm not doing it as well`, `I'm not doing it either` are right

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please take the site [tour] and review the [help] for guidance on how to compose answerable questions here. All four are grammatical, but not all are idiomatic, and your second option can be misinterpreted as saying *I am doing it, but with less quality or skill than someone else is doing it*.

Answer (score 0):

Your first is correct.
The second sounds like you may be doing it, but poorly.
The third and fourth would sound right if you *were* doing it.

You could also say, *Neither am I*.